# Are there any foods that would be permissible for Jews to eat, yet forbidden for non-Jews to eat?

Tags: gentiles, food

I found numerous examples in the opposite direction, food which Jews may not eat but which is permissible to non-Jews, but nothing in the direction I'm looking at

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=90453&rid=15002

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the religion of the non-Jew and maybe whether or not they care about offending Jews?

Comment: @nick012000 this is a site about Judaism, so I understand the OP's question to be about the Jewish perspective of what non-Jews are allowed to eat, which comes from the Seven Noachide Laws.

Answer (score 4):

See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38217/difference-between-eiver-min-hachai-for-jews-and-noahides#:%7E:text=Jews%20are%20allowed%20to%20eat%20pieces%20taken%20from,if%20it%20is%20still%20convulsing.%20%28Simla%20Chadasha%2027%3A1%29) which contains the following:

> This leads to an interesting paradox -- after an animal was killed,
> while it is still moving, it is permitted to Jews and forbidden to
> non-Jews.

To understand in detail please read it all.

Answer (score 3):

There is dispute between Rabbi Yochanan and Reish Lakish if חצי שיעור אסור מן התורה, half measurements are biblically forbidden. According to Reish Lakish, it isn't, and according to Rabbi Yochanan, it is. (See [Yoma 74a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.74a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Shiurim/Halachic Measurements are something exclusive to Am Israel.

There is a prohibition of אבר מן החי, taking the limb of a live animal, to both Jews and non-Jews. According to the above, according Reish Lakish, biblically a half-measurement of such a limb is permitted for Jews but forbidden for non-Jews.

Comment: "Shiurim is something exclusive to Am Israel." How do you know that?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94894/1739

Comment: Rambam Halachot Melachim perek 9 halacha 10
שֶׁלֹּא נִתְּנוּ הַשִּׁעוּרִין אֶלָּא לְיִשְׂרָאֵל בִּלְבַד

Tosfot on Chulin 33a d"h אחד עובד כוכבים ואחד ישראל מותרין בו asks what I wrote above and concludes that according to Reish Lakish, the klal of דליכא מידי is not true.

Comment: See my link. Also, I think it's Hilchot not Halachot, as it's smichut.

Answer (score 2):

A non Jew may not partake in Kodshim as the Rambam writes in Maaseh Korbonos perek 10:9 that one must be pure and be circumcised.  However ,they may bring a Korban Olah.

> כָּל הַקָּרְבָּנוֹת בֵּין קָדְשֵׁי קָדָשִׁים בֵּין קָדָשִׁים קַלִּים אֵין אוֹכְלִין אוֹתָם אֶלָּא הַטְּהוֹרִים בִּלְבַד הַמּוּלִין. אֲפִלּוּ הֶעֱרִיב שִׁמְשׁוֹ וְלֹא הֵבִיא כַּפָּרָתוֹ אֵינוֹ אוֹכֵל בְּקָדָשִׁים. וְהַטֻּמְטוּם אָסוּר לֶאֱכל בְּקָדָשִׁים לְפִי שֶׁהוּא סְפֵק עָרֵל אֲבָל הָאַנְדְּרוֹגִינוּס יֵרָאֶה לִי שֶׁאוֹכֵל בְּקָדָשִׁים קַלִּים:

From the Mechilta Perek 13:passuk 43 writes that this includes a non jew who is called an arel lev. This is in reference to the Korban pesach which we learn out Kodshim(see Yevamos 70).

> כל בן נכר לא יאכל בו. אחד ישראל מומר ואחד נכרי במשמע. שנאמר וכל בן נכר ערל לב (יחזקאל מד)

Comment: Non jews can't be pure and circumcised? There must be a more explicit source

Comment: When I have a minute will form a more through answer ,has to do with a genara in Yevamos where we learn Kodshim from pesach...

Comment: We can't give kodshim to a non-Jew, but is there an issur for him to eat it by himself? Let's say there's no gneivah (belonged to a ger who died or something).

Comment: From the gemara in pesachim 3 we see that they cannot eat it at all,see the story there...

Comment: That's an explicit prohibition regarding the Korbon Pesach. You know it's true for other korbonos as well? Also, I think I read somewhere that that story was a horaas shaah. I think the Rambam says the prohibition is to feed it to them.

Comment: The gemara in Yevomos is mashma that we learn all kodshim from Korban pesach

Comment: @DoubleAA Miderabanan, all non-Jews are like zavim/zavos. So no, at least on that level they can't be tahor and be able to eat korbanos.

Comment: @Meir do they have לא תסור?

Comment: @Heshy True, probably not, but I was just addressing the point of whether they could be pure. Your earlier point (first comment) seems implicit in [Minchas Chinuch 13:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Chinukh.13.1.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he): אמאי לא נימא דהעועכו"ם עצמו מוזהר ע"ז... הן אמת גבי ב"נ צ"ל כן דהתור' לישראל נאמרה ולא לעכו"ם חוץ מהמנוים בסנהדרין שבע מצות... (Although I see where later on, in 14:1, he says that the Semag does hold that it's a prohibition on the non-Jew himself, and indeed that this is why the guy in Pesachim 3b that sam mentioned was executed.)